# How to save the information on a Page when traveling from one detail page to another

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, master-detail

I am working with Xamarin.Forms and I am trying to implement my multipage form in a Master-Detail format. When I click on another page from the Master page menu, I want to make sure that the information on the current detail page gets saved to its respective database table on the mobile device before I travel to the next detail page. Any idea on how to achieve that?

Comment: You could use sqlite database. About store Data in a Local SQLite.NET Database, you could refer to the links below. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/databases https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/get-started/quickstarts/database?pivots=windows If you want to save it before travel to the next detail page, suggestion ro use `OnDisappearing` in the reply would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the OnDisappearing() method?

```
protected override void OnDisappearing()
{
    //Your code before you switch to another page
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi @lovetolearn you can achieve this things OnDisappearing() method of each page.

```
protected override void OnDisappearing()
{
    //Your code before you switch to another page
}
```